# Creating hyperlinks from an MRU binding

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, binding, hyperlink

(I'm very very new to WPF and C#, so be gentle, please!)

I'm trying to create a "start page" for our application which will feature the 5 most-recently-used projects in hyperlink form (inside a TextBlock?).

There are bindings available already within the project. If I do a ListBox like this...

```
<TextBlock Margin="51,189,0,223.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="177" Background="#FFEBEAEA">
<ListBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentProjects}" ItemTemplate="{Binding}">
</ListBox>
</TextBlock>
```

...I get the full path of the previous projects. I'd like to strip them down to just the filename (and maybe even drop the extension) in hyperlink format, then set the action of the click to our "Open file" command with the filename as a parameter.

If anyone can guide me to good resources for doing non-web hyperlinks, acting on items within a collection, that would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good question, your XAML would probably look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecentProjects}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding OpenCommand}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayFileName}"/>
                        </Hyperlink>      
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And then the class would look like this:

```
class Class1
{
    public List<Project> RecentProjects { get; set; }

    public class Project
    {
        public ICommand OpenCommand { get; set; }

        public Project()
        {
            OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenFile);
        }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string DisplayFileName
        {
            get { return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName) ; }    
        }

        public void OpenFile(object sender)
        {
            // Open the file here e.g.
            Process.Start(FileName);
        }
    }  
}
```

RelayCommand is a custom class detailed in the MVVM tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051) that will allow you to use delegates to deal with the commands.

Good luck!